# How to access the return value from outside the function in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I wanted to access the value of the function outside in Django rest framework. I have checked this function which return value but I want to call that return value in another function.
I have tried this approach where I'm getting output ticketid as 'None'

```
views.py:
  
def GetUserTaskId(request):
    userid = request.data.get('UserId')
    ReportId = request.data.get('ReportId')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetUserTaskId] @UserId=%s, @Ticket=%s', (userid, ReportId))
    result_set =cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result_set:
          TaskId=row[0]
        return Response({"TaskId":TaskId})

def inserttask(request):
       ticketId = GetUserTaskId(request)
       print("ticketId--->",ticketId)
       if ticketId is not None:
         /***somecode***/
```

Comment: You could move the logic to get the ID into a third function that is called by both `GetUserTaskId` and `inserttask`.

Comment: I wanted to execute this inserttask function only after validating the ticketId so I can't both move into another function

Comment: Is `inserttask` a view function?

Comment: yes inserttask s a view function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like this?

```py
# common.py

def get_task_id(user_id, report_id):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetUserTaskId] @UserId=%s, @Ticket=%s', (user_id, report_id))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result_set:
        TaskId=row[0]
        return TaskId
```

```py
# views.py

from .common import get_task_id

  
def GetUserTaskId(request):
    userid = request.data.get('UserId')
    ReportId = request.data.get('ReportId')

    task_id = get_task_id(userid, ReportId) # call our function

    return Response({"TaskId": task_id})


def inserttask(request):
    userid = request.data.get('UserId')
    ReportId = request.data.get('ReportId')

    ticketId = get_task_id(userid, ReportId) # call our function

    print("ticketId--->",ticketId)
    if ticketId is not None:
        pass
        # somecode
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, I have modified your answer  and implemented both function in single views.py